# PhpStorm tag to forbid/prevent commit

Tags: git, phpstorm

Is there any tag or secret word in PhpStorm or maybe in git itself that would raise an alarm if I'd try to commit a file with new line marked with this secret tag?

For real use case let's say I sometimes change a file just to test something or simulate some special behaviour. However this line should be never changed in repository.

Can I mark this kind of lines with a special tag like "@gitignore" so PhpStorm will automatically exclude this file from commit list? Or show a warning if I'd still try to commit it?

I know people from JetBrains are watching this tag. If there is no such possibility, thing about it as feature request.

Comment: I do not know such tags (which does not mean that it does not exist). The only options I know and may suggest are: 1) TODO comments -- IDE can show a list of them so that you may decide to abort your commit;  You may configure special kind of comments to be highlighted a bit differently (diff colors/icon) to attract your attention.

Comment: 2) use "PHP Inspections (EA Extended)" plugin -- one of the inspections it has called "Probable bug: forgotten debug statement" where you can add your class method/function name. You will have to call such method/function in your code though (it's not just a comment); If you have "Inspect code before submitting" enabled then IDE will show them as errors and should prevent from committing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in phpstorm.
Write for example

```
//@todo @gitignore
```

And set checkbox "Check TODO". Then configure todo filter.
[image]
Every time you commit, phpstorm will inform you about todo tasks.